# Python if one condition is met, print "..."

Tags: python

I am a student that is rather nee to learning programming languages, i decided to pick up Python and am really enjoying it so far.
I might have a stupid question but i cant seem to find a solution, i have written a part of a program and the user inputs 3 values. if even one of those values breaks a statement it should print out the correct answer.
This is what i have..

```
lengte = input("Wat is de lengte die u nodig hebt?")
breedte = input("Wat is de breedte die u nodig hebt?")
hoogte = input ("Wat is de hoogte die u nodig hebt?")
a = 140
aa = 100
aaa = 110
b = 220
bb = 115
bbb = 120
if(hoogte in range(a) and breedte in range(aa) and hoogte in range(aaa)):
    print "Type A"
if(hoogte in range(a,b) or breedte in range(aa,bb) or hoogte in range(aaa,bbb)):
    print "Type B"
```

BUT when i give in 170 for hoogte and 40, 40 for breedte and hoogte it still prints out "Type A" while in my eyes it should say "Type B" because the value exceeds aa but is lower as bb..

any help would be appreciated, sorry if this seems like a "noob" question.. but yeh i am pretty new to this.

Comment: `input` gives a string, which is just plain text. Text and numbers are different, so you have to convert hoogte to an integer by wrapping it: `int(hoogte)`. Only then can you test whether or not it is in a range of _numbers_. Edit: Ignore this, I didn't realise it was Python 2.

Comment: That's python2, so `input` gives an int.

Comment: Oh oke thanks, ill give it a try and let you know soon :D

Comment: you don't use lengte in the if statement

Comment: @WalidSaad oops i forgot that here but it is in the code i am using for the program

Comment: You say, "*i give in 170 for hoogte*" and "*40, 40 for breedte and hoogte*". Which is it? Do you give 170 for hoogte or 40 for hoogte?

Comment: Can you correct the code here and the rest of the question to refer to `hoogte` and `lengte` where you mean them? In you question you say "170 for hoogte and 40, 40 for breedte and hoogte". It is unclear whether you mean `hoogte` is 170 or 40. If it is 40 then, because you check `hoogte` twice and `lengte` not at all then you will get Type A.

Answer (score 1):

May be you mis-type the first condition. You type it hoogte, but it may be lengte.

```
if(lengte in range(a) and breedte in range(aa) and hoogte in range(aaa)):
    print "Type A"
if(lengte in range(a,b) or breedte in range(aa,bb) or hoogte in range(aaa,bbb)):
    print "Type B"
```

The first conditional logic will only print "Type A" if all conditions are true, while the second will print "Type B" if at least one condition is true.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you specify a,aa,aaa and so on as ranges, but you give no range. So instead use == operators to test whether your input is equal to any of the variables you have specified.

This worked for me.

```
lengte = input("Wat is de lengte die u nodig hebt?")
breedte = input("Wat is de breedte die u nodig hebt?")
hoogte = input ("Wat is de hoogte die u nodig hebt?")
a = 140
aa = 100
aaa = 110
b = 220
bb = 115
bbb = 120

if(hoogte ==a and breedte == aa and hoogte == aaa):
    print "Type A"
if(hoogte ==a,b or breedte == aa,bb or hoogte == aaa,bbb):
    print "Type B"
```

Comment: actually this will just always print "type B" since the first conditional would need `hoogte==a and hoogte==aaa` which will always be False as long as `a!=aaa` but the second conditional has comma's in the statement which means it is actually checking a tuple for truth, try: `print (hoogte ==a,b or breedte == aa,bb or hoogte == aaa,bbb)` a tuple with more then 0 elements will always be considered True.